# How to install windows and other softwares from usb drive Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, usb, installation, usb-flash-drive

I'm wondering if it's possible to install Windows 7, XP along with other software after the Windows installation. All in one shot. The 'other software' would be eg: Nero, Antivirus, etc.

I know it's possible to do, I found a tutorial a long time ago but I didn't save it. I've found how to do the Windows installation but I'd like to automate everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options here.  If your program comes in a MSI file, you can insert them into a Setup DVD using a tool like nLite or WAIK(Windows Automation(?) Installation(?) Kit).

The second method is if your application doesn't include a MSI is to start with a clean install and then install your programs and make any setting changes you want.  You can then run Microsoft's Sysprep on the computer and it will package your install into an image you can then deploy to multiple computers.

The first one takes little if no effort.  The second one takes a lot of effort and trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to initially configure a system with everything installed and then use a backup imaging software like Symantec Ghost or Acronis True Image to make your back up images. If you need to reinstall to that machine then you will just boot from the recovery disc and then point to the image you created.

The issue with this will be if you need to restore your image to another machine. You'll run into legal issues with licensing and probably BSOD due to hardware profiles.